# How to statically link libstdc++

Tags: c++, g++, static-linking, libstdc++

I am trying to get my program working in another machine where libstdc++ versions is different. I am developing and compiling it on netbeans. I have specified the option -static-libstdc++ but the program continues trying to load libstdc++.so.6 in the local machine.

How can I get a fully static libstdc++ link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of the exact circumstances here, but I ran into a similar problem just now with different versions of Mac OS X and gcc.  I worked around it by copying the actual dylib I wanted into the same directory as the executable and changing `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to have it search there first before /usr/lib.