# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found

Tags: c++, linux, unix

It turns out that "make install" - the make target that installs and implies the target "install-target-libstdc++v3" doesn't actually mean you're ready to go.

I've been stuck for a while wondering what I was doing wrong because I assumed that such a make target would do that for me.

Comment: sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9

Comment: If you are the programer that compiler the the program, you can add `-static` to the gcc command line to static link your program. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636513/linking-libstdc-statically-any-gotchas

Comment: I vote to reopen: this is the top google result for this error message, so having the answers frozen is a real disadvantage.

Comment: @Owen it's actually been closed several times - IIRC this was my third posting (seriously) - however the error and the "fix" on this page are not really properly dealt with here. Just a specific case yielding the error.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

## Add the library's path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable

### TL;DR

GCC requires you to tell it where your library is located manually when it can't find the right version, which can be done in a few ways. One is adding it to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

For some, the library path will be `/usr/local/lib64/`. Others have reported the library path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` working for them instead.

### Why do we need to add the library to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

When you compile and install GCC it puts the libraries in one of these directories, but that's all it does. According to the [FAQs for `libstdc++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths), the error that we got means that the dynamic linker found the wrong version of the `libstdc++` shared library. Because the linker can't find the right version, we have to tell it where to find the `libstdc++` library.

> The simplest way to fix this is to use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, which is a colon-separated list of directories in which the linker will search for shared libraries.

There are other ways as well to fix this issue. You can find this and the other solutions mentioned briefly when you install `gcc` if you read the make output:

> Libraries have been installed in:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/../lib32
> ```
>
> If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR' flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
>
> - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable during execution
> - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable during linking
> - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
> - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
>
> See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.

Grr, that was simple! Also, "if you ever happen to want to link against the installed libraries," seriously?

Comment: You generally *don't* want to link against random versions of libraries that you just installed. Your software will not run on any other machine. It is usually better to use the older versions of the libraries that are included with your operating system. If you do need to build libraries then you'll have to include all of them when distributing your software. And if your software is another library which is linked to yet another library which is using a third version of libstdc++ then your program is just not going to work.

Comment: @ZanLynx isn't that the point of the .x.y.z we have? So it's not random? I suppose not everything specifies a version (hence the default symlink) right?

Comment: What if the directory /usr/local/lib64 does not exist? I do have libstdc++6 and gcc 4.8 installed.

Comment: @cxrodgers then just lib, I assumed you'd have a 64bit system

Comment: I do have a 64-bit system. I get the same error no matter whether I add /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/lib64 (which doesn't even exist) to my path. The library appears to be located at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 but it doesn't help to add this to the path either. Perhaps this needs to be its own question.

Comment: @cxrodgers then you need to post a question yes

Comment: @AlecTeal The problem is that you don't want *every program* to link against the new lib *at run time*, which is what LD_LIBRARY_PATH does.  See http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html

Comment: this work for me. conda install -c anaconda tensorflow

Comment: @AlecTeal Kind of worked but I don't have that `/usr/local/lib64`, only `/usr/local/lib` so my program is throwing another error

Comment: @o0ragman0o are you working with GCC too? Or are you here for the same problem in a different area? I found this in GCC's output (scroll up a bit when it's done) - see hat yours says.

Comment: @AlecTeal ran into it after trying to update an application which turns out to have been compiled in 4.9. I was still on Mint 17 (ubuntu14.04) which has 4.8. Have ended up doing a full upgrade to Mint 18.3 rather than manhandle library paths and such

Comment: I don't think that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` needs to be its own question. It's just another location and it works just fine, it sounds like @cxrodgers was just accidentally putting the file and not the directory in the path. The following works for me: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"`.

Comment: Thanks. I had this error when trying to make mysql-8 from source.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem on my [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) when I tried to install TopTracker. I got such errors:

> /usr/share/toptracker/bin/TopTracker:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.8' not
> found (required by /usr/share/toptracker/bin/TopTracker)
> /usr/share/toptracker/bin/TopTracker:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not
> found (required by /usr/share/toptracker/bin/TopTracker)
> /usr/share/toptracker/bin/TopTracker:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.9' not
> found (required by /usr/share/toptracker/bin/TopTracker)

But I then installed the [GCC 4.9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/) version (2014-04-22) and the problem was gone:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

Answer (score 10):

I've got correct solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/581497/528593).

The best way to correctly **install gcc-4.9 and set it as your default gcc version** use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9
```

The --slave, with g++, will cause g++ to be switched along with gcc, to the same version. But, at this point gcc-4.9 will be your only version configured in update-alternatives, so add 4.8 to update-alternatives, so there actually is an alternative, by using:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
```

Then you can check which one that is set, and change back and forth using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

NOTE: You could skip installing the PPA Repository and just use /usr/bin/gcc-4.9-base but I prefer using the fresh updated toolchains.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still gives the same error.

Comment: what if I don't have sudo access? then how can implement your approach?

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was gcc 6 the one missing

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6 -y
```

### Update

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7 -y
```

Comment: As for now, you could use `sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7 -y`

Answer (score 3):

This solution works in my case. I am using [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus), [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) 2.7.2 and [Genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/genymotion/info) 2.7.2.
The same error comes in my system. I have followed simple steps and my problem was solved:

1. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
2. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
3. `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9`

Answer (score 2):

What the other answers suggest will work for the program in question,
but it has the potential to cause breakage in other programs and unknown dependence elsewhere.  It's better to make a tiny wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
program_needing_different_run_time_library_path
```

This mostly avoids the problem described in [Why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is bad](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html) by confining the effects to the program which needs them.

Note that despite the names LD_RUN_PATH works at link-time and is non-evil, while LD_LIBRARY_PATH works at both link and run time (and *is* evil :).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue on my Ubuntu-64 system when attempting to import fst within python as such:

```
    Python 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun  4 2015, 15:29:08)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ogi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyfst-0.2.3.dev0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/fst/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fst._fst import EPSILON, EPSILON_ID, SymbolTable,\
ImportError: /home/ogi/miniconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libfst.so.1)
```

I then ran:

```
ogi@ubuntu:~/miniconda3/lib$ find ~/ -name "libstdc++.so.6"
/home/ogi/miniconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/ogi/miniconda3/pkgs/libgcc-5-5.2.0-2/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/ogi/miniconda3/pkgs/libgcc-4.8.5-1/lib/libstdc++.so.6
find: `/home/ogi/.local/share/jupyter/runtime': Permission denied
ogi@ubuntu:~/miniconda3/lib$

mv /home/ogi/miniconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /home/ogi/miniconda3/libstdc++.so.6.old
cp /home/ogi/miniconda3/libgcc-5-5.2.0-2/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /home/ogi/miniconda3/lib/
```

At which point I was then able to load the library

```
ogi@ubuntu:~/miniconda3/lib$ python
Python 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun  4 2015, 15:29:08)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fst
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error when installing PhantomJS on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with gcc-4.8 (CXXABI_1.3.7)

Upgrading to gcc-4.9 (CXXABI_1.3.8) fixed the issue. HOWTO:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04