# Mint: genymotion installation bug

Tags: android, installation, genymotion, linux-mint, xcb

I'm newbie with Mint. I installed Genymotion emulator from the `.bin` file in /home/user/Android directory. And when I'm trying to execute Genymotion I receive such message:

> /Android/genymotion $ ./genymotion
>
> ./genymotion: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libdouble-conversion.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

As I understood from quick search I should link this conversion library. But I'm aware to do something wrong ;) Could someone advice proper way for doing this. Preferably with some explanation.

**UPDATE**

After I used @Atheror suggestion I got another message:

> ./genymotion
>
> ./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
>   `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by
>   /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libQt5Core.so.5)
>
> ./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
>   `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by
>   /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libQt5WebKit.so.5)
>
> ./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
>   `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by
>   /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libicui18n.so.52)
>
> ./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
>   `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by
>   /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libicuuc.so.52)
>
> ./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
>   `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by
>   /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libicuuc.so.52)

**UPDATE**

After some additional search I tried to add missing libraries. After this, attempt to run genymotion leads to such record in genymotion.log:

> [Genymotion] [Fatal] This application failed to start because it
>   could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, kms, linuxfb, minimal,
>   minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

So xcb plugin is available. After another quick run in web I found suggestion to check dependencies by using `ldd` command and got:

**platforms # ldd   libqxcb.so**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff97ec000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f6b14c5d000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f6b14a4d000)
libxcb-render-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render-util.so.0 (0x00007f6b14849000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f6b14641000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f6b14425000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6b14221000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f6b1400a000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f6b13e01000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f6b13be2000)
libxcb-image.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-image.so.0 (0x00007f6b139dd000)
libxcb-icccm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-icccm.so.4 (0x00007f6b137d8000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f6b135d2000)
libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007f6b133cb000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f6b131c8000)
libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007f6b12fbb000)
libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007f6b12db7000)
libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1 (0x00007f6b12bb4000)
libxcb-xkb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xkb.so.1 (0x00007f6b1299a000)
libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 (0x00007f6b12792000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f6b12558000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f6b1231c000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f6b12079000)
libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007f6b11dfa000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6b11af2000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f6b118e8000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f6b115b3000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f6b10f66000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f6b108c0000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f6b1062e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6b10410000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6b10103000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6b0fdfd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6b0fa38000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f6b0f826000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f6b0f621000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6b14e5f000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f6b0f41d000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f6b0f217000)
libxcb-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.0 (0x00007f6b0f010000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f6b0ede6000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6b0ebcd000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f6b0e9a7000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f6b0e762000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f6b0e524000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f6b0e2cf000)
libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0x00007f6b0dec8000)
libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007f6b0db4f000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6b0d947000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6b0d730000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f6b0d506000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f6b0d303000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f6b0d0fd000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f6b0cef8000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f6b0ccf5000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f6b0caf2000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f6b0c8f0000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f6b0c6ea000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f6b0c4dd000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f6b0c2c1000)
libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007f6b0aa54000)
```

So I assumed that problem in linux-vdso.so.1 and tried to solve this by installing this library with apt: **sudo apt-get install linux-vdso.so.1**
but got error that this package doesn't exist. So I am again in a deadlock:(

Comment: Got the same issue when I tried to use .bin file for `Ubuntu 15.04 and newer` in my Mint-17.3, I downloaded the  .bin file for `Genymotion for Ubuntu-14.10 and older` and installed it, it works.

Comment: I got the same errors. I've tried below ones but the were not helping. I've used this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/37817792/2369484. This may need below one or may not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue on Linux Mint 17, installing genymotion 2.7.2 here: [How to fix: [program name] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by [program name])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/how-to-fix-program-name-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxx)

I just need to do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

Answer (score 19):

Solved for me on Ubuntu 15.10 with:

```
sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1v5
```

on Ubuntu 14.04 and MINT it should be:

```
sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm very sorry for late update, but this approach leads to another issue

Comment: sorry to hear that, Mint 17 is based on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) so any installer for Trusty should work on it. Tell me if you already solved it or need more help, Im using Mint and Ubuntu. Genymotion is working really good on both.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, based on comment of @Atheror:

It may be a problem of your **Linux OS and Genymotion compatibility**. Check version of your Linux using command in terminal:

```
inxi -S
```

or

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

**And try to install the previous version of Genymotion.**
For my Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14.04) installing and runing *'Genymotion for Ubuntu 14.10 and older'* gives no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this in xubuntu 16.04 using:

```
sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1v5
```

And running ./genymotion again.

Answer (score 0):

Run following commands in terminal (ALT+CTRL+T)

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9

after that run the genymotion. that will work perfectly