# How to fix Genymotion in linux ElementaryOS with error `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found

Tags: android, c++, linux, ubuntu, genymotion

Whenever I am trying to start genymotion(run command ./genymotion), the following error shown in my terminal

```
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/mgumiero9/genymotion/libQt5Core.so.5)
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/mgumiero9/genymotion/libQt5WebKit.so.5)
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/mgumiero9/genymotion/libicui18n.so.52)
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/mgumiero9/genymotion/libicuuc.so.52)
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/mgumiero9/genymotion/libQt5Qml.so.5)
```

I would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: Vipin Jain. Thank you for the edition. Now, It's more clear to read. I appreciated it.

Comment: The same errors for Mint 17.3

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Execute the following **5 steps** to solve it:

---

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

---

In my case this method worked like a charm.

Comment: Worked for me as well ;)

Comment: Made my day! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was losing it.

Comment: Thanks Worked for me as well :)

Comment: it will be very nice if anyone explain what cause this problem and why system need to put these codes into `terminal` . i know about codes above completely but i dont know why these need now !

Comment: Thanks a lot guy! Thanks a lot guy!

Comment: Hey... A few days ago Google implemented a similar virtual machine technology in its default emulator... So, in case that there is no need to have very granular controls, you can you can use it.