# genymotion install ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, genymotion

I install the genymotion in ubuntu 14.04.
I run the ./genymotion this command to get below error.

```
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/vinothdev/Documents/Software/genymotion/libQt5Core.so.5)./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/vinothdev/Documents/Software/genymotion/libQt5WebKit.so.5)    ./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/vinothdev/Documents/Software/genymotion/libicui18n.so.52)    ./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/vinothdev/Documents/Software/genymotion/libicuuc.so.52)    ./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/vinothdev/Documents/Software/genymotion/libQt5Qml.so.5)
```

Anyone help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605623/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-the-file-libstdc-so-6-0-15

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Genymotion in linux ElementaryOS with error `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817792/how-to-fix-genymotion-in-linux-elementaryos-with-error-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found)

Answer (score -1):

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```