# libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by bin/opencv_test_core)?

Tags: gcc

I've installed OpenCV and haven't received errors during `CMake` and `make install`. However, when I tested the installation by running some test tasks, I received these errors.

```
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by bin/opencv_test_core)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by bin/opencv_test_core)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by bin/opencv_test_core)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by bin/opencv_test_core)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2)
bin/opencv_test_core: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /data/projects/st/software/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2)
```

After some Googling, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/how-to-fix-program-name-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxx), but it's not that convenient for me to install `gcc-4.9`, as I am not the root. It's been really painful for me to manually install packages to my local directory...

I do have `gcc-6.4` installed (when I do `which gcc`, I see its directory). Can I somehow configure my system to make it work with `gcc-6.4` (e.g., adding it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? I am not sure as a Linux newbie)? Or do I have to install `gcc-6.4`?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I am having the same problem and I have gcc, g++ 5.4.1, so that is greater than the 4.9 version that everyone recommends.