# Issue compiling with different version of gcc and g++

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

I want to compile a program by entering through `SSH` the computer at my institution. I want to compile this program by using a different version of `gcc` and `g++`, namely a more recent one with repsect to the default installed one. This means that instead of using `gcc-4.9.2` and `g++-4.9.2` I would like to use `gcc-6.3` and `g++-6.3`. I can find them already on my computer, in fact I have the folder `/opt/gcc-6.3`, so I don't have to download them. So what I do is the following

```
export PATH=/opt/gcc-6.3/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-6.3/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

but while `gcc` seems to work, when I try to compile a `c++` program with `g++` I get

```
./[name_of_the_program].x: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./[name_of_the_program].x)
./[name_of_the_program].x: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./[name_of_the_program].x)
```

Obviously, if that's relevant information, I am not `root` on this machine.

Comment: Possibly duplicate with [`How to fix: [program name] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by [program name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/how-to-fix-program-name-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxx)

Comment: A major breaking change was made when GCC version 5 was made that affects C++ code. See [the online manual about the Dual ABI"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a 64bit machine, you must add

```
/opt/linux-gnu_6.x.x/lib64
```

path also to you environment. ( or which path on your machine is used for the libs of this compiler version )

If you get root access you should better add ( or maybe your admin should do! )
your library path information to

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/gcc63.conf
```

and run `sudo ldconfig`.

After that you should check with `ldd` comand, that all chained requirements are fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
export PATH=/opt/gcc-6.3/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-6.3/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Instead, add:

```
-B/opt/gcc-6.3/lib/
```

to your invocation options for either of the frontends `gcc` or `g++` (assuming that `/opt/gcc-6.3/lib/` is indeed the directory that directly
contains the GCC 6.3 toolchain executables and libraries).

See the documentation of the [-Bprefix option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)

Example:

```
$ cat prog.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "I was compiled with GCC " 
        << __GNUC__ << '.' <<  __GNUC_MINOR__ << '.' << __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__
        << " to C++ standard " << __cplusplus << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

$ which g++-4.9
/usr/bin/g++-4.9

$ which g++-6
/usr/bin/g++-6

$ g++-4.9 -o prog prog.cpp && ./prog
I was compiled with GCC 4.9.4 to C++ standard 199711

$ g++-4.9 -B/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0 -o prog prog.cpp && ./prog
I was compiled with GCC 6.2.0 to C++ standard 201402
```

As per others' comments, be aware g++ >= 5 is ABI incompatible with `g++` < 5.