# Visual Studio Code run code in the terminal

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

error when run terminal :

The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my RHEL 7.9 laptop. I downgraded VS Code to the last version that works - 1.52.1, and prevent it from auto updating:

```
# sudo yum downgrade code-1.52.1
# sudo yum versionlock add code
```

Cheers