# /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/chilkat_9_5_0.so (/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found

Tags: server, vps, libstdc++

I am trying to use a PHP extension (chilkat_9_5_0) on VPS server. after adding it, it gives below error message:

```
 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'chilkat_9_5_0.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/chilkat_9_5_0.so (/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/chilkat_9_5_0.so)), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/chilkat_9_5_0.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/chilkat_9_5_0.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I have looked for possible solutions, and found that GCC is an old version, so I have upgrade it to 6.5.0
however, I facing the same issue. in the server terminal I executed a search command and it appears that libstdc++.so.6 is pointing to the previous version of GCC:

[image]

also, I tried this solution, but still same issue:

[/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found)

can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. Maybe you need to link libstdc++.so.6 to the just installed version of libstdc++ manually ?

```
root@lenovo:~# ldd /usr/bin/gcc
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff3c8c76000)

root@lenovo:~# ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/|grep libstdc
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 19 maj 13  2022 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.30 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2252096 maj 13  2022 libstdc++.so.6.0.30
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe3c8eb7000)
```

You can also use `ldconfig -p` to see libraries in the local cache

```
root@lenovo:~# ldconfig -p |grep libstdc++.so.6 
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Thanks but I got an error message no such file exist

Comment: actually this has caused that the whole server now is not working