# libstdc++ system libraries not stripped on OpenBSD and FreeBSD

Tags: c++, freebsd, libstdc++, openbsd

I am doing some research whether to compile C++ libraries static or dynamic for a new project. (I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636513/linking-libstdc-statically-any-gotchas), also). I saw that on OpenBSD and FreeBSD the system libraries are a lot bigger (5-7 MB) than on Linux (1.5 MB) because they are not stripped. So I have 2 questions:

1. The OpenBSD libestdc++.so is any different than libstdc++.so? I didn't find any info on it, google just corrects me, removing the "e" letter from the word.
2. Why these libraries are so big on BSD? If I would like to deploy or statically link them they will be huge. Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of FreeBSD are you talking about? Because FreeBSD 10 seems to use LLVM `libc++` instead.

Comment: I am using FreeBSD 10.3 and it seems that gcc is using stdlibc++, not libc++. I created a simple C++ 14 binary and these are its dependencies:
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/gcc49/libstdc++.so.6 (0x800820000)
    libm.so.5 => /lib/libm.so.5 (0x800b33000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x800d5c000)libc.so.7 =>     /lib/libc.so.7 (0x800f6a000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OpenBSD, `libstdc++` is the base c++ library (GCC 4.2), `libestdc++` is installed from ports (GCC 4.9 or 6). The libraries are installed with symbols on OpenBSD, you can strip the symbols with `strip -s libwhatever.so`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I saw that I can strip the symbols but my concern was whether I will "break" (our build machines are used by many teams) anything if I will do this. Or perhaps I can make a duplicate of libestdc++, strip it and link my binary with the stripped one?

Comment: You will not break the dependencies of the lib. However, the package tools will complain due to the different checksums. My suggestion is to use a virtual machine to strip and link statically the libs and then to move those to production.