# Is possible to include the standard library libstdc++ so I don't need to install it on my target?

Tags: c++, standard-library, libstdc++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to statically link libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917413/how-to-statically-link-libstdc)

I want to make sure to use the same version of the standard library on my target platform.
So is there a way to compile it with my program?

Comment: `-static-libstdc++`.

Comment: @LokiAstari According to the libstdc++ tag, its g++.

Comment: @Mark: Clang can be used with libstdc++ just aswell.

Comment: @Xeo Well, thanks for the info. But I think libstdc++ cannot remain at that status forever.

Comment: this question was asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917413/how-to-statically-link-libstdc

Comment: @Mark: It's not libstdc++ that is portable (they don't declare `class type_info;` inside of `<iostream>` but use it and GCC works around it with a compiler hack), but Clang behaving ~99% like GCC (except for Clang, you need to do `namespace std{ class type_info; }` before including `<iostream>` when using libstdc++...).